# SQLite - REGEXP functionality for "C" / ODBC applications

Tags: sqlite, odbc

I am working on a small "C" SQLite text-oriented application that communicates via **ODBC**, using the "{SQLite3 ODBC Driver}".
How can I enable access to **REGEXP** functionality when working with  this set of development tools?

Thanks

Hillel

Comment: That would depend on which ODBC driver you are using. Although, if you are writing an application in C, I don't see why you don't just use sqlite directly from your code.